# Initializing new object inside collectionView's itemForCellAtIndexPath takes too long (up to 100ms)

Tags: ios, realm

### Goals & expected results

Good performance when using RLMResults as datasource for collectionView.

Question is: how do I speed things up so that my UI doesn't hang for 1/10th of a second every time I add a new item into the displayed list?

### Actual Results

Initializing one cell takes up to 100ms when accessing a new instance of a Realm object for the first time.

### Code Sample

Message object has the following properties:

```
dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
dynamic var chatUserId = ""
dynamic var messageId: String? = nil
dynamic var directionRaw = "out"
dynamic var message: String? = nil
dynamic var mediaId: String? = nil
let read = RealmOptional<Int64>()
let received = RealmOptional<Int64>()
dynamic var created: Int64 = 0
dynamic var pending = false
```

DataSource for my collectionView is:

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
 self.messages = realm.objects(Message).filter("chatUserId = %@", chatUserId).sorted("created", ascending: false)
```

Place that takes 90ms is:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MessageViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MessageViewCell
    let message = messages![indexPath.row] // 90ms!!!
    cell.messageTextLabel.text = message.message!
    return cell
}
```

### Version of Realm and Tooling

Realm 0.98.3

### EDIT:

The issue conversation was continued on GitHub: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3312

Comment: I have a similar problem when loading ~200 objects into a TableView. The UI hangs for about 6 seconds. What tool did you use to isolate the problem to that line of code?

Comment: I suspected it was the cell creation so I added a simple NSDate() calculated timer there. I later found out it was a totally different issue actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question leaves out a number of important details in order to help you. The following are questions you should ask yourself when profiling Realm performance:

### 1. How many `Message` objects are in your database?

The more objects you have, the more Realm will need to search to perform the initial query. If you have 5 items when it takes 90ms to perform the initial query, that's quite slow and should be reported to the Realm team for more performance analysis. If you have a million items in your database, then 90ms is pretty good! Odds are that your data set lives somewhere in the middle there.

### 2. Is your `Message.chatUserId` property indexed?

Realm (like most databases) has the ability to mark a property type as *indexed*, which will slow down writes but accelerate certain kinds of queries, such as queries for equality. If these kinds of queries are performance-critical in your app, you should consider indexing them. Be sure to profile the impact of this in your app on a real device though to truly assess if it's the right move for you!

You can learn more about indexing in Realm here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#indexed-properties

### 3. What device & build configuration is this benchmark run on?

Realm's performance can easily be affected by running in debug or release mode. Debug mode has better debugging information while release mode is faster but has fewer checks. Whenever running benchmarks or profiling for performance, you should run your app on a real iOS device with your app built in Release mode.

How much pressure the device is under will also impact performance. For example, disk I/O memory and contention, CPU usage, number of threads access a Realm file, etc.

---

After all this, if you still believe Realm's performance in this situation to be unreasonable, I encourage you to file an issue on Realm's GitHub repository along with a benchmark sample project that reproduces this poor behavior: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new

**Update:** also, Realm has mechanisms in place to efficiently keep queries live and always up to date (see docs on [Auto-Updating Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#auto-updating-results)) so subsequent accesses of the results should be faster than the initial one.